# 'Unexpected token in JSON' when trying to save emojis to a file and the parse the file back to json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, unicode, emoji

```js
    const message = { message: 'Thanks again ' };

    const res1 = await fs.writeFileSync('test123.json', JSON.stringify(message));
    const fileBuffer = await fs.readFileSync('test123.json');

    const json = JSON.parse(fileBuffer.asciiSlice()); // can't parse JSON
```

Gives me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 26
    at eval (repl:1:6)
```

How can I save this json with emojis to a file so that I can parse it back to json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `{ encoding: 'utf8' }` when reading the file. Now it returns as a string with the correct emojis.

```js
const res1 = await fs.writeFileSync('test123.json', JSON.stringify(message));
const string = await fs.readFileSync('test123.json', { encoding: 'utf8' });
const json = JSON.parse(string);
```